# Resolve circular import issue

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongoengine

I am creating an app using Flask with MongoEngine to connect to MongoDB.
My folder structure looks like this:

```
app/
    __init__.py
    mod_users/
        __init__.py
        constants.py
        forms.py
        models.py 
        views.py
    mod_games/
        __init__.py
        constants.py
        forms.py
        models.py 
        views.py
```

Let's say my User and Game models are like the following:

mod_users/models.py

```
class User(db.Document):
    email = db.EmailField()
    username = db.StringField()
    password = db.StringField()
```

mod_games/models.py

```
from app.mod_users.models import User

class Game(db.Document):
    title = db.StringField()
    creator = db.ReferenceField(User, reverse_delete_rule=db.CASCADE)
    likes_count = db.IntField()
```

Now, my problem is that I would like the User to have a list of the game he likes. But I cannot use a reference field because I would have to import Game which would create a circular import.

This won't work:

```
from app.mod_games.models import Game

class User(db.Document):
    email = db.EmailField()
    username = db.StringField()
    password = db.StringField()
    liked_games = db.ListField(
        db.ReferenceField(Game, reverse_delete_rule=db.PULL)
    )
```

I thought about storing in every game a list of users who liked it, and then adding a static method in Game that would retrieve
a list of liked Game for a given user, but that doesn't seem to be a clean and efficient way to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you have an answer - MongoEngine does cater for this as you can pass the string name of the class to a reference field eg:

```
class User(db.Document):
    email = db.EmailField()
    username = db.StringField()
    password = db.StringField()
    liked_games = db.ListField(
        db.ReferenceField('Game', reverse_delete_rule=db.PULL)
    )
```

Comment: It will need to be imported somewhere yes - but not necessarily in models.py. However, if you make all the ReferenceFields use the Model name as a string then you won't have any circular references...

Comment: But where could I import all my models so that mod_x/models.py can access it?

Comment: Thats up to how you organise your app - you could use `app/__init__.py` or whereever you set up the mongodb connection.

Comment: @Ross Could you provide complete sample showing how are modules organized and how are the imports done?

Answer (score 1):

## M:N relationships to be modelled via Association class

Game and User have a relationship, where one Game can be liked by any number of Users and one User can like any number of Games.

This is typical M:N relationship, and this is to be modelled by an association class (take it as class modelling rule).

The class should have:

- reference to User
- reference to Game
- any additional properties of this particular relationship, e.g. how many stars the use gave to this game.

The tuple User - Game must be unique.

When defining this type of class, you import from User and from Game module.

User and Game shall not import this association class (otherwise you would enter into circular references problem again)

Answer (score 0):

As it was [mentioned before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24859907/7744106) you can pass a string name of a model to a reference field. That is the first thing you should do to avoid circular imports:

```
class User(db.Document):
    company = db.ReferenceField('Company')
```

But when you have a method that uses some model, let's say, to aggregate some data, this way above doesn't helps - you still may get an circular imports issue. To resolve this try `get_document` function. See example below.

```
from mongoengine.base.common import get_document as get_model

class User(db.Document):
    # fields definition omitted

    def get_games(self):
        Game = get_model('Game')
        games = Game.objects.filter(user=self.pk)
        # some code here
```